# how to destroy a singleton object when i can't find any api about it

Tags: java, gephi

When I use Gephi-tookkit to draw the graph in java. But i find the problem of memory leak.I use the MemoryAnalyzer to analy the dump,it show the ProjectController make the this problem.
This class ProjectController is singleton in gephi.

```
ProjectController pc = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(ProjectController.class);
```

I want to destroy this class ,how can I do?

Comment: By _destroy_ you mean... ?

Comment: @icza, if this is a memory leak problem, I think he wants to free memory of pc object.

Comment: A singleton cannot be a memory leak - there is only one instance of it.

Comment: A singleton may be a memory leak, when singleton contain a List.When you create a singleton or doing some options,the list will be large.But I can't destroy it.I want to make Object in LookUp equal null.

Comment: You can see the code https://github.com/gephi/gephi/blob/master/modules/ProjectAPI/src/main/java/org/gephi/project/impl/ProjectControllerImpl.java

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem using java reflect.You can hack the class of Lookup,and change the field to null.

```
public static synchronized void cleanUpLookup(){
    Lookup obj = Lookup.getDefault();
    Field field;
    try {
        field = Lookup.class.getDeclaredField("defaultLookup");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(obj, null);
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```